# How to delete images in Media Library without deleting the file in server in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have used  a plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/best-import/ in oder to import all images from server into my wordpress media lirabry. Unfortunately, I had mistakenly uploaded many necessary files.

Now, want to delete these files from MEDIA without deleting those in server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your admin panel go to media, you will render all your files. Then click bulk select, select all the files you wish to delete, then click delete selected. This will just delete it off your site.
A good plugin for this is Product CSV importer (You can download just products or all files)

Comment: Nope, that deleted the files from the server, too (using WordPress 4.9.6)